# Is it possible to use audio to make a liquid (such as water) resonate?

Tags: resonance, vibrations

I am a graduate student studying wireless perception, and recently I want to carry out liquid recognition. I want to use a speaker as a sound source to generate vibrations (by playing sounds of different frequencies). My idea is that different liquids have different resonant frequencies. When the frequency of the external force is close to the resonant frequency of the liquid itself, the liquid's The amplitude will be larger, so different liquids can be identified. I would like to ask you if my idea is reliable and can you tell me some theoretical knowledge, such as whether the amount of liquid also affects the resonant frequency?

Comment: Welcome Muller Thomas to Physics Stack Exchange. People are already trying to do this.  See, for example, ["Akte-Liquid: Acoustic-based Liquid Identification with Smartphones"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3551640) or ["Identification of Solid and Liquid Materials Using Acoustic Signals and Frequency-Graph Features"](https://doi.org/10.3390/e25081170).

Comment: thanks a lot, David